# Convert binary to decimal in Julia

Tags: julia

I'd like to convert binary to decimal in Julia. It looks like `parseint()` became deprecated.

Is the below method the best way to do this?

```
julia> parse(Int,"111",2)
7
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you starting with a string?  Then yes, that's the way.  If you're just wanting to write a constant in binary, then it's much easier to just use the `0b111` syntax.  By default, it constructs an unsigned integer (which is displayed in hexadecimal), but you can easily convert it to a signed integer with `Int(0b111)`.

```
julia> 0b110111
0x37

julia> Int(0b110111)
55
```