# What is the replacement for dec() function in julia?

Tags: julia

**dec()** => a String representation showing that what the decimal version would be.

```
julia> dec(0x10)
ERROR: UndefVarError: dec not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[1]:1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert binary to decimal in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46451829/convert-binary-to-decimal-in-julia)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`string`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.string) function:

> ```
> string(n::Integer; base::Integer = 10, pad::Integer = 1)
> ```
>
> Convert an integer n to a string in the given base, optionally
>   specifying a number of digits to pad to.
>
> ```
> julia> string(5, base = 13, pad = 4) "0005"
>
> julia> string(13, base = 5, pad = 4) "0023"
> ```

Since `base` defaults to `10` in your case you can do:

```
julia> string(0x10)
"16"
```